# Insert record from one table from another table base on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Record should be insert into Table B from Table A, condition both all Id's of Table A who have RoleId=1 should be availabe in Table B using SQL query

Table A

```
Id     RoleId
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        2
5        2
```

Table B

```
Id
1
```

Output: Table B

```
Id
1
2
3
```

I tried below query but not able to write conditions

```
insert into Table B (Id) select Id from Table A where roleId=1
```

Comment: insert into Table B (Id)
select Id from Table A
where roleId=1 .@Dale K

Comment: I am confusion to write condition. @DaleK

Comment: Can you check updated answer mr dale k. @DaleK

Comment: That answer is giving error. @DaleK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

```
insert into tableB (Id)
select Id from TableA
where RoleId = 1 
and not exists (select 1 from TableB where TableA.id = TableB.ID)
```

Comment: not exist condition you have wrote roleid but roleid is TableA. @eshirvana

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan actually you don't need that ,see my updated answer

Comment: i am getting this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'. @eshirvana

Comment: not exist condition is giving error. @eshirvana